# Runtime objects from JSONSchema in C#

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

You can validate an object using a JSON Schema.

You can generate dynamic objects at runtime with dynamic and expanddo

What I would like to do, is generate objects at runtime from JSON Schemas, that can then be populated as necessary.

If this seems weird, the reason is the JSON Schema will define a template to be populated from another source, but the system allows you to create new templates.

Example as requested:

Parent Object

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public decimal DecimalValue { get; set; }
    public double DoubleValue { get; set; }
    public float FloatValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTimeValue { get; set; }

    [EnumDataType(typeof(EnumData))]
    public string EnumValue { get; set; }

    public List<Child> children { get; set; }
}

public enum EnumData
{
    Alpha,
    Beta,
    Charlie
}
```

Child Object

```
public class Child
{
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
    public int ChildInt { get; set; }
}
```

Resulting JSON Schema

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Id": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "Name": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ]
    },
    "IntValue": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "DecimalValue": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "DoubleValue": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "FloatValue": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "DateTimeValue": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time"
    },
    "EnumValue": {
      "type": [
        "string",
        "null"
      ],
      "enum": [
        "Alpha",
        "Beta",
        "Charlie"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Id",
    "Name",
    "IntValue",
    "DecimalValue",
    "DoubleValue",
    "FloatValue",
    "DateTimeValue",
    "EnumValue"
  ]
}
```

The schema is a definition of an object.  If this definitions was created by a user choosing what properties they want, they type, acceptable values etc, then a schema could be generated.

If you could then create an instance of an object from this schema, the properties could be populated.

The point is the class won't be known at coding time.

The reason for this is we have a huge generic set of data that we need to create smaller sets from, that the user defines what these sets will be from inside the application.  The definition they create can be stored and used again.

Comment: It's not really clear what are you trying to do and why. Could you please give some examples of such JSON and Schema, and any relevant code? At the same time, could you elaborate why do you want to do it, what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You also mentioned some "system". Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh hopefully the updated question explains things better

Comment: Your wish sounds like a Roslyn component.. there is a code example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381483/roslyn-dynamic-class-generation-issue

Comment: @Goodies - I'll take a look at Roslyn

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with my new library, [JsonSchema.Net.Generation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net.Generation).

```cs
var schema = new JsonSchemaBuilder().FromType(myType);
```

You can read more about it [in the docs](https://gregsdennis.github.io/json-everything/usage/schema/generation.html).

Comment: I'm afraid this is the opposite of what I want, this generates a schema. I want to generate an object, something like Object obj = JsonUtilLib.ObjectFromSchema(jSonSchema)

Comment: You post on your question "Resulting JSON Schema" meaning that you want to finish with the schema. This is what my library does.

Answer (score -1):

I think @gregsdennis got the library right. If you look at the documentation it can be done.

```
The NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration can be used to generate C# or TypeScript code from a JSON schema:

var generator = new CSharpGenerator(schema);
var file = generator.GenerateFile();

The file variable now contains the C# code for all the classes defined in the JSON schema.
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my phone so couldn't read it properly, will check when I get home.